# CSS align UL side by side

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have two unordered lists whose elements are side by side.  I am having a hard time figure out how to put these  lists side by side.  Right now it appears like:

Add 1 Add 2

Add 3 Add 4 Add 5

I need it to looks like this:
Add 1 Add 2 Add 3 Add 4 Add 5

Here is my css and HTML including a fiddle I have been using.
    ul,ol         { list-style:none; }

```
.product-view .sharing-links a {
  background-image: url(../images/icon_sprite.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

.product-essential {margin-bottom:0px; padding-bottom:25px;}
.product-view .product-essential .product-shop .nobr {margin-bottom:5px; display:inline-block;}

.product-view { margin-bottom:20px;}
.product-view .product-shop {float:right;width:100%;}

.add-to-box { background-color: #F4F4F4; border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC; }
.add-to-box .add-to-links  { float: left; }

.product-view .add-to-links { margin-left:25px !important; padding: 15px 0 5px;  border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; width: 100%; float: left; }
.product-view .sharing-links { float: left; }

.product-view .add-to-links li {margin-bottom: 8px; display:inline-block; }
.product-view .add-to-links li a:before { font-size: 14px; margin-right: 15px; color:#2E8AB8; }
.product-view .add-to-links li .link-wishlist:before { }
.product-view .add-to-links li .link-compare:before { }


.product-view  .sharing-links:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.product-view .sharing-links li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 7px 7px;
}
.product-view .sharing-links a {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
}
.product-view  .sharing-links a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.product-view .sharing-links a.link-email-friend {
  background-position: 0px -322px;
}
.product-view  .sharing-links a.link-facebook {
  background-position: 0px -425px;
}
.product-view  .sharing-links a.link-twitter {
  background-position: 0px -372px;
}

<div class="product-view">
    <div class="product-essential">
        <div class="product-shop">
            <div class="add-to-box">
                <ul class="add-to-links">
                    <li>Add 1</li>
                    <li>Add 2</li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="sharing-links">
                    <li>Add 3</li>
                    <li>Add 4</li>
                    <li>Add 5</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/23y6o7dj/

Thanks for any help!  Im sure its something obvious :/

Comment: You set `width: 100%;` on `.product-view .add-to-links`.

Comment: Its not floating because the .add-to-links width is set to 100%. Remove it and the ul's will float.  also add the padding: 15px 0 5px to .sharing-links

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/23y6o7dj/1/ Anything else is causing a problem.

Comment: You guys always find this stuff so fast!  Thanks a ton, probably looked at these lines over 100 times and continued to miss that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the value of `width:100%` to `width:auto` and remove the `padding: 15px 0 5px;` proprety from the `.product-view .add-to-links` CSS style:

```
.product-view .add-to-links { 
     margin-left:25px !important;  
     border-top: 1px solid #DBDBDB; 
     width: auto; 
     float: left; 
}
```

This is [**the working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/23y6o7dj/5/).